# Including libraries fails - what is document root?

Tags: ajax, phantomjs, mocha.js, karma-runner, browserify

I have a file (`src/inc.js`) that loads certain files into my browser using jquery's ajax:

```
$.ajax({url: 'somefile.js', async: false, dataType: 'script', 
    error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(
            '[' + textStatus + '] ' 
            + errorThrown + ' with: ' + this.url
        );
    }
});
```

and this file gets included via browserification into my browser (phantomjs).  `Gruntfile.js`:

```
browserify: {
    libs: {
        src: ['src/*.js'],
        dest: 'test/libs.js'
    }
}
```

and handed to karma (in `Gruntfile.js`):

```
karma: {
    options: {
        files: ['test/libs.js']
    }
}
```

but when it runs the file can't be found:

> `aprilis:test ekkis$ grunt test-web`
>
> Running "browserify:libs" (browserify) task
>
> > > Bundle test/libs.js created.
>
> Running "karma:phantom" (karma) task
>   25 01 2016 18:36:56.498:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.16 server started at http://localhost:9877/
>
> 25 01 2016 18:36:56.506:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
>
> 25 01 2016 18:36:58.424:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket wqi-DFYcij9hs0_6AAAA with id 61800957
>
> 25 01 2016 18:36:58.489:WARN [web-server]: 404: /somefile.js?*=1453775818448
>   PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LOG: '[error] Not Found with: ./somefile.js?*=1453775818448'
>
> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 128 of 128 (1 FAILED) (0.029 secs / 0.047 secs)
>   Warning: Task "karma:phantom" failed. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

(do notice that the server complains about `/somefile.js` but the path (logged) was provided as `./somefile.js`.  this also happens if the path provided is `../somefile.js` ends up as `/somefile.js` as well)

I'm assuming that when phantomjs runs the document root is the root of the project? so in that case perhaps `$.ajax({url: 'test/somefile.js'` should work? it doesn't.  what is the document root when the run is made (where am I supposed to put the file so I can access it)?

Comment: out of curiosity, why not just using the script tag?

Comment: this is just an example.  the reality is more complicated.