# Serving script files from karma server

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm running tests on phantomjs via the karma runner and some of my code makes ajax calls which all fail with a 404.

I've struggled with where to place the file (see: [Including libraries fails - what is document root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006306/including-libraries-fails-what-is-document-root)) but I came across a post ([Loading external file from Karma/Jasmine test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938320/loading-external-file-from-karma-jasmine-test)) that indicates I can configure the karma web server to serve other files.

in particular the ajax calls are attempting to load files from the `node_modules` directory so I've configured the `karma.config.js` like this:

```
files: [{
    pattern: 'node_modules/*',
    served: true,
    included: false
}]
```

and my ajax calls look generally like this (I've placed a `blah.js` in the directory for testing):

```
$.ajax({url: 'node_modules/blah.js', ...});
```

but still it doesn't work.  what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... this is odd but according to the [karma docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/files.html):

> By default all assets are served at http://localhost:[PORT]/base/

so this works: 1) in the `karma.conf.js`:

```
files: [{
  pattern: 'node_modules/**',
  served: true,
  included: false
}]
```

and 2) the call:

```
$.ajax({url: '/base/node_modules/blah.js', ...});
```

...which leaves the question of how that `base` can be configured, but for now, this works.